# Define each block in database gem migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just wondering is it possible to define each block in rails `gem data-migrate` to avoid repetition like below?

```
class DisableTaxField < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
def change
  company_group = Group.find_by(name: 'company_data')
  tax_nr = company_group.inquiry_fields.find_by(name: 'tax_nr')
  tax_nr.update!(required: false)

  data = Group.find_by(name: 'data')
  tax_id = data.inquiry_fields.find_by(name: 'tax_id')
  tax_id.update!(required: false)

  data = Group.find_by(name: 'personal_data')
  tax_id = data.inquiry_fields.find_by(name: 'tax_id')
  tax_id.update!(required: false)

  data = Group.find_by(name: 'acting_person')
  tax_id = data.inquiry_fields.find_by(name: 'tax_id')
  tax_id.update!(required: false)
end
end
```

Because only the name changes as you see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe create array with this values? For example:

```
class DisableTaxField < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  GROUP_NAMES = %w[company_data data personal_data acting_person].freeze

  def change
    GROUP_NAMES.each do |group_name|
      tax_value = group_name == "company_data" ? "tax_nr" : "tax_id"
      data = Group.find_by(name: group_name)
      tax_nr = data.inquiry_fields.find_by(name: tax_value)
      tax_nr.update!(required: false)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think it is what I'm looking for, but how to implement if `GROUP_NAMES == company_data` should be `tax_nr = data.inquiry_fields.find_by(name: 'tax_id')` everything else should be `tax_nr = inquiry_fields.find_by(name: 'tax_nr')` ?

Comment: oh didn't notice that there is a difference with this value. I will update my answer